Black captions are CMYK, not RGB
I am writing a book, and my publisher wants the caption text to be entirely black. From the looks of it, it seems black to the naked eye, but apparently it's in CMYK whereas it should be RGB(0, 0, 0). I am using Overleaf to write and compile my document. Example code for captions below:
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[font={small,sf}]{caption}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figure.png}
    \centering
  \caption*{This caption looks like it's black, but apparently it's not.}
\end{figure}

If you have any ideas how to fix this, I'd be very happy! Thanks in advance.

Hi. Difficult to say, impossible to test if you do not provide a full, compilable example showing the problem.

Guess: Try to load xcolor with option RGB.

RGB(1, 1, 1) is almost certainly not the colour that you want. RGB values either range from 0–1, in which case RGB(1, 1, 1) is pure white, or they range from 0–255, in which case RGB(1, 1, 1) is a very dark grey. If all values are in the range 0–1, black can be any of RGB(0, 0, 0), CMYK(1, 1, 1, 0), or CMYK(0, 0, 0, 1).

Thanks! @MaxChernoff - I meant 0, 0, 0 of course, my bad. I'm investigating and will come back with an answer if I get it to work.

From your code fragments can be only concluded that text in captions hase the same color as have main text. How you see it, is depends on type of monitor which you use.

The problem in this case was the figures themselves. I used PNGs in an RGBA configuration, which had the unintentional effect of adding color coding on the black caption text. I am not sure why this happened, but according to my publisher the problem has been resolved.
A working solution in this case was to convert the figures to JPG on a white background (the color of the page), keeping the caption configuration.
